# MonoTouch NSKeyedUnarchiver

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, nskeyedarchiver

looking for help with NSKeyedUnarchiver  in Monotouch

Storying an Array of Dictionary items in an SQLite blob field

**IOS Code**

```
NSData     *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:ptr length:size];
NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:data];
NSMutableArray *myArray = [unarchiver decodeObjectForKey:@"pricing"];
[unarchiver finishDecoding];
NSMutableArray *MutData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSDictionary *obj in myArray) {
     NSMutableDictionary *element = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:obj];
     [MutData addObject:element];
}
```

Trying to convert to MonoTouch,  so far I have

**MonoTouch Code**

```
NSData data = NSData.FromString(item.pricing);

NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchive =  new NSKeyedUnarchiver(data);
unarchive.DecodeObject();
unarchive.FinishDecoding();

NSMutableArray array = unarchive.GetNativeField("pricing") as NSMutableArray;
NSMutableArray mutArray = new NSMutableArray();

for (uint count=0; count < array.Count; count++)
{
    NSMutableDictionary mutDict = new NSMutableDictionary(array.ValueAt(count));
    mutArray.Add(mutDict);
}
```

Produces and Error at runtime

> Unhandled managed exception: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name:
>   NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: *** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver
>   initForReadingWithData:]: incomprehensible archive (0x62, 0x70, 0x6c,
>   0x69, 0x73, 0x74, 0x30, 0x30)
>   (MonoTouch.Foundation.MonoTouchException)   at (wrapper
>   managed-to-native)
>   MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Messaging:monotouch_IntPtr_objc_msgSend_IntPtr
>   (intptr,intptr,intptr)   at
>   MonoTouch.Foundation.NSKeyedUnarchiver..ctor
>   (MonoTouch.Foundation.NSData data) [0x00027] in
>   /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/Foundation/NSKeyedUnarchiver.g.cs:88
>   Stacktrace:

From the new NSKeyedUnarchiver(data) line

One  can someone suggest tutorials / examples for MonoTouch NSKeyedUnarchiver ?

Two  can someone help with this error ?

Last Is this the best way in light that the project is to be cross platform and work under Android (eventually)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The problem is likely with the how you create the initial NSData.

[This](https://github.com/mono/maccore/blob/master/src/Foundation/NSData.cs#L66) is what NSData.FromString does, which doesn't quite look like what you're doing in Objetive-C.

If you have a pointer available in C#, try using `NSData.FromBytes` instead.

Comment: Thanks  sadly, trying FromBytes  had not helped either.  It will run though but everything is blank/empty/null  except for the initial byte[] item.pricing.     anything else I can try

Comment: do you get the same exception with FromBytes?